# How to insert random values in an array with max lenght and max array sum

Tags: php, arrays, random

So, i need to make an array with lets say `$n = 100` (max array length) and `$target = 50` (max array values sum) with random numbers between 0-20.

I've tried with the below code but it gets - values when y<x.

```
$target = 50;
$n = 100;
while ($n) {
    if (0 < $n--) {
        $addend = rand(0, $target - ($n - 1));
        $target -= $addend;
        $addends[] = $addend;
    } else {
        $addends[] = $target;
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems like more of a "solve this problem for me" than a specific debugging question.

Comment: I assume this is homework. You are not checking anywhere if target gets below zero. Add a variable $sum to keep track of the total of the numbers that are already in the array and compare that with the value of target.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try next code as approach:

```
<?php
$addends = [];
$max_count = 100;
$max_sum = 50;
$max_value = 20;

for($i=0; $i<$max_count; $i++) {
    // generate random value between 0 and $max_sum, but not grate when $max_value
    $value = rand(0, min($max_value, $max_sum));
    // echo "rand(0, min($max_value, $max_sum)) = $value \n";
    
    // decrease $max_sum to $value
    $max_sum -= $value; 
    
    // store value into array
    $addends[] = $value;
}

print_r($addends);
print_r(array_sum($addends));
```

Here you can try it: [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=301f0cd6763a6540480723829060a05c&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: Thanks @Slava Rozhnev, it works well.